# 2D array vs. structure (C++)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct

If execution speed is important, should I use this,

```
struct myType {

    float dim[3];
};

myType arr[size];
```

or to use a 2D array as `arr[size][index]`

Comment: Why do you think there'd be any difference?  Have you timed it both ways, on your specific configuration?

Comment: It probably won't matter. However, if speed is important to you, *measure* both methods on your target platform.

Comment: If speed is important, write what's the most maintainable and let the compiler optimize it for you. (Unless you benchmarked and found a bottleneck there, of course, which is the only good excuse for an exception to that rule.)

Comment: Just for giggles, you should also profile with *four* floats and see if there's a difference. It's a space-vs-alignment trade-off, but worth giving a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use case. If you use the three dimensions typically together, the struct organization can be reasonable. Especially when using the dimension individually the array layout is most likely to give better performance: contemporary processors don't just load individual words but rather units of cache lines. If only parts of the data is used there are words loaded which aren't used.

The array layout is also more accessible to parallel processing e.g. using SIMD operations. This is unfortunate to some extend because the object layout is generally different. Actually, the arrays you are using are probably similar but if you change things to become `float array[3][size]` things become different.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter. The compiler will produce the exact same code regardless in almost all cases. The only difference would be if the struct induced some kind of padding, but given that you have floats that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all. Pick what is more readable to you.

Unless you're working on some weird platform, the memory layout of those two will be the same -- and for the compiler this is what counts most.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is when you pass something to a function.
When you use the array solution, you never copy the array contains but just pass the array address.
The structs will always be copied if you don't explicitly pass the struct address in case of the struct solution.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to keep in mind that another poster mentioned: If dim will always have a size of 3 in the struct, but the collection really represents something like "Red, Green, Blue" or "X, Y, Z" or "Car, Truck, Boat", from a maintenance standpoint you might be better off breaking them out. That is, use something like

```
typedef struct VEHICLES  
{  
  float fCar;  
  float fTruck;  
  float fBoat;  
} Vehicles;
```

That way when you come back in two years to debug it, or someone else has to look at it, they will not have to guess what dim[0], dim[1] and dim[2] refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to map out the 2d array to 1d. Might be more cache friendly